# ajax success response change as @html.raw

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonresult

I have following jquery code in my Razor viewpage

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var grouplistvalues = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Session["grouplist"]));


    $("#nsline").click(function () {

        alert(grouplistvalues)

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SetupGroups",
            data: { grouplist : grouplistvalues },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response)
            {
                grouplistvalues = null;
                grouplistvalues = response;
                alert(response)
            },
            error: function ()
            {

            }
        });

    });


    $("#ewline").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SetupGroups",
            data: { grouplist : grouplistvalues },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response)
            {
                grouplistvalues = null;
                grouplistvalues = response;
            },
            error: function ()
            {

            }
        });        

    });
```

in above `grouplistvalues` its taking session as html raw

when I alert it on `#nsline` click function I can see it,

[image]

in above function I'm calling to ajax function and above `grouplistvalues` value updating

once I alert it on `#nsline` click function success response I can see a alert like folllowing
[image]

since this(`grouplistvalues` value) `1,2,..` changing as `[1,2..]` I cannot call to other ajax function in `#ewline` click function since parameter difference,

this is the above common ajax call

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SetupGroups(long[] grouplist)
    {
        Session["grouplist"] = null;

        List<long> groupList = new List<long>();

        foreach (var groupitem in grouplist)
        {
            groupList.Add(groupitem);
        }

        long[] grouparray = groupList.ToArray();
        Session["grouplist"] = grouparray;

        return Json(grouparray);
    }
}
```

Though I have two click functions its work with only the first click(ewline or nsline only the first time)

How to solve this

Comment: You work with long array, so why do you want a format like X,Y,Z ... ?  So your code is currently working ! I tested your code and it works

Comment: no its compiling without any issue, and once I debug its work with first click, I think that because this response change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the `dataType` in your ajax request. It should be `json`:

```
dataType: "json"
```

Comment: really? I tested with your code and found out that `dataType: html` causes your action `SetupGroups` to return a string `"[1, 2]"` instead of a json array `[1, 2]`. That's why from the second request, parameter `grouplist` is always null.

You can try to evaluate the response in `success` callback: `grouplistvalues = eval(response);` for a work around if you still want to keep `dataType: html`.